# Why it value does not send in to ajax post?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, ajax

I'm a newbie working with ajax. I have a problem while sending the data into ajax post.
The output of `console.log(obj.Id)` and `console.log(oke)` is 2. Then I tried to send it through data in ajax, but it end up 0 in the controller.

```js
$(function () {
            $("body").on('click', '#btnEdit', function () {
                alert("clicked ok");
                $("#addRowModal").modal("hide");
                var obj = {};
                obj.Id = $(this).attr('data-id');
                oke = $(this).data("id");
                console.log(obj.Id)
                console.log(oke)
 
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("Details", "InvoicePPh")',
                    data: oke,
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert("sukses");
                    },
                    error: function(response) { 
                        alert("error") 
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

And my controller looks like this

```html
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Details(int id)
        {
            var obj = dbContext.invoicePPhs.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
            InvoicePPh pph = new InvoicePPh();
            pph2326.TaxForm = obj.TaxForm;              
            return Json(pph);
        }
```

I want the '2' value that passes into my controller, how can I do that? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try using a viewmodel to accept data in the controller and send it through a JSON object from ajax,

Comment: You should change `data: oke,` to `data: obj,`

Comment: according to your error it seems that jQuery is not defined properly double check that  or if its there check the sequence of your js reference .. it should come first or before that code ......... also if you have 1 parameter then you can simply data: {id : oke  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative way to send your data your `Controller` method using `Ajax` would be to wrap your data in a `JSON` object and then send it to the server for processing. The server will be then deserialize your `JSON` object and you can access the required properties from that process:

```
$(function () {
    $("body").on('click', '#btnEdit', function () {
        alert("clicked ok");
        $("#addRowModal").modal("hide");
        var obj = {};
        obj.Id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        oke = $(this).data("id");
        console.log(obj.Id)
        console.log(oke)

        var json = {
           oke: oke
        };
        
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Details", "InvoicePPh")',
            data: {'json': JSON.stringify(json)},
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert("sukses");
            },
            error: function(response) { 
                alert("error") 
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And your `Controller` method will be:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Details(string json)
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    dynamic jsondata = serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(object));

    //Get your variables here from AJAX call
    var id= Convert.Int32(jsondata["id"]);
    var obj = dbContext.invoicePPhs.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
    InvoicePPh pph = new InvoicePPh();
    pph2326.TaxForm = obj.TaxForm;              
    return Json(pph);
}
```

Comment: hmm.. it gave me 'null' value in 'string json'. but in ajax, it already gave me '6' value as example.

Comment: Remove contentType from the ajax request.

Comment: I get error in 'serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(object));' then I tried remove ' typeof(object)' and the error is gone but it doesnt work and the result still id = 0.

Comment: What error do you get ? Can you post that error ? Also what do you see in your json object on your Controller method ?

Comment: The errors:
1. 'using System.Web.Script.Serialization;' is not found in my environment. I'm using .NET 6, then I installed another package but still not working
2. 'var id' error in db parameter then I changed into 'int id'
2.  The jsondata result is "(\"oke\":6}"
3. Then when run into 'int id', it turns out 0 again

Comment: Error for deserialize is 'No overload for Deserialize method'

Comment: it works, when i change top3 code in controller with this,
string result = new string(json.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());
int id = Int32.Parse(result);

Comment: @TiaraDwiDikiyanti Okay, you can also use `Newtonsoft` package to deserialize your `JSON` string that you receive from the `Ajax` call. `var jsondata=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);` and then get your values like: `var id=Convert.ToInt32(jsondata.oke);`

Answer (score 0):

Please change the data property in ajax part.

```
          $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Details", "InvoicePPh")',
                data: { 'id': oke },
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert("sukses");
                },
                error: function(response) { 
                    alert("error") 
                }
            });
```

Comment: it keeps getting a '0' value:(

Answer (score 0):

If you just need id in your method parameter just change data in ajax to:

```
 contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
 data: { 'id': oke },
```

id is name of parameter from controller method.

Comment: it keep getting '0' value:(

Comment: I saw you solved the problem above but maybe changing `contentType` from `json` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` should work with my solution.
I have been using schema like this:
```contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  data: { 'playerId': playerId },
```

Comment: yaap, you're right. I remove the contentType then it started to work well. Thank you so much for your help